# RPi not booting into system

Tags: raspbian, boot, boot-issues, touchscreen

I just followed a couple of steps to try to configure a eGalax Touch Screen monitor, and always, after installing the three programs listed in the picture, the RPi gets stuck in a black screen with a white blinking underline. I have formatted it a couple of times, and it keeps happening each one of them. Any idea what I could do to solve it?[image]